# I Need the Z-Machine's Circuit Diagram

Tags: experimental-physics, fusion

Where can I find a copy of the circuit diagram for [Sandia Lab's Z-Machine](https://www.sandia.gov/z-machine/), or indeed for any pulse forming network that outperforms the ordinary Marx bank (if such a thing exists)? Google has let me down in my search for this information. TIA.

Answer (score 2):

A recent [Physics of Plasmas](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/full/10.1063/5.0007476) on the Z Machine has a high level overview with copious references to the fundamental technology. However, it is not clear just how detailed of a 'circuit diagram' you want. Simulations using standard electrical engineering analysis tools, while useful as rapidly calculated analogs of the machine, do not capture the full physics of the power flow.

Comment: Where can I find the information to learn what DOES capture the full physics of the power flow?

Comment: @JohnSchutkeker - section III.E in that paper is on power flow.